# Poor query performance depending on the placement of `where` conditions (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, performance, where

There is a query, in which changing the ordering of `where` conditions affects its performance drastically (5k vs 700k rows_examined).

The weird thing is that both versions of the query have the exact same plan when I use `explain` and `explain for connection`. However, the number of examined rows when I run them is vastly different.
From what I read the ordering of conditions doesn’t matter, as the optimizer will try to fix the query, but this is not the case here. Am I missing something?

I'm using MySQL 5.7

Comment: When asking performance question always include table descriptions, explain plan and in your case the query used . Data examples and expected result would be great as well, because the query might be written differently

Answer (score 0):

I have seen as many as 6 different explain plans for a single query.  The plan varies because:

- The constants in the query matter.
- The "statistics" can be refreshed via `ANALYZE TABLE`.  (Doing such often does not make any difference.)
- "Examined rows" cannot be computed without running the query.  `EXPLAIN` gives an estimate, sometimes a very crude estimate.
- The slowlog, if turned on and configured adequately, will list the exact number of "rows examined" and "rows returned" for the one case.
- `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` gives more info.